# Google App Engine: localhost browser caching?

Tags: google-app-engine, http, browser-cache

I'm developing with GAE on my own machine. It was pretty fast, until I added CSS and images, at which point the page loads much more slowly. I suspect that the browser isn't caching anything, perhaps because GAE isn't setting any far-future expiration headers in the HTTP request. Is there anything I can do to get around this?

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
self.response.headers['Expires'] = "10 Dec 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
```

Adding this to `app.yaml` works better:

```
default_expiration: "100d"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting [caching options for static files](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers)?